# Determinant of $n\times n$ matrix $|i-j|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For integer $n$ greater than or equal to 2, let $A_n$ be $n^{th}$ order square matrix whose $(i,j)$ component is $|i-j|$. That is,
\begin{align*}
    A_n =\begin{pmatrix} 
    0& 1& 2& ... & n-1\\
    1& 0& 1& ... & n-2\\
    2& 1& 0& ... & n-3\\
    .& .& .& ... & . \\
    .& .& .& ... & . \\
    .& .& .& ... & . \\
    n-1& n-2& n-3& ... &0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Find the determinant of $A_n$.

We have two general tools for the determinant of $n\times n$ matrix, they are co-factor formula and the Leibniz formula but I tried to build an expression for the determinant of this matrix but failed, Any hints would be appreciated.

Leibniz Formular : $\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\bigg(\text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}\bigg) $ I can figure this out for $3\times 3$ matrices but it is hard to think for $n\times n$ matrices with these permutations $\sigma$.

And how do we find these kind of problems on the internet? Any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: I think it should be $(-1)^n \cdot n \cdot 2^{n-1}$

Comment: Ohh..could please tell me the way of thinking?

Comment: Replace the columns $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ by $v_1,v_2 - v_1,v_3 - v_2,\ldots,v_n - v_{n-1}$ so that your matrix becomes mostly $\pm 1$'s. Then pull a Laplace extension.

Comment: I guess it is only a little issue in the definition of $n$. By calculating the first terms, I get $(-1)^{n-1} \dot (n-1)2^{n-2}$ @JeroenvanderMeer

Comment: @Damien You may very well be right. I didn't double check my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering for closure. Let me write $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ for the columns of $A$. Now consider the matrix with columns $v_1,v_2 - v_1,\ldots,v_n - v_{n-1}$. It looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots &1& 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1&1 \\
2 & -1 & -1 & 1 & \cdots &1& 1 \\
3 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & 1& 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots& \vdots \\
n - 2 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & 1\\
n - 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
No apply Laplace expansion on the bottom row to obtain a recurrence relation between $\det A_n$ and $\det A_{n-1}$. Use this to prove that, in general,
$$\det A_n = (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)2^{n-2}.$$

Comment: Here we are applying the Laplace expansion along the column one right?

Comment: I had expansion along the bottom row in mind but I'm sure that expanding along the first column should also work!

Comment: If you do the same thing with the rows that you did with the columns, you will get a simpler matrix to do Laplace expansion on.  You get 0 in the top left, -2 on the rest of the diagonal, and 1's in the first row and column (except for the top left).  I don't know that the reccurence you get is simpler, but it it seems more evident to me what to do with the further reduced matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much